# I am unable to sign in with Microsoft account to whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp

I have tried adding whatsapp into my phone but it didn't happen while logging in to the account an error appeared saying:

> We are unable to connect, make sure you have a good reception, if you do the problem may be at other end. Wait for a while and try again.

I have been trying for three hours, can any one help me?

Comment: Make sure the time and date is correct on your phone. Also, visit the WindowsPhone.com website and confirm your account is working.

Comment: @NeilTurner yes time is not correct, can you guide me to set the time and date

Comment: thanks, i got it i.e. got my time and date corrected and its working now

Comment: Great, I'll put that as the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the **time and date** on your Windows Phone are correct. If they are not, you will be unable to purchase or download apps.

To change the time and date, look in **Settings** > **Date+Time**. You may need to turn off the "Set date and time automatically" option to set the time/date manually.